# Apple Homekit setup hash

Tags: hash, server, installation, homekit

I'm trying top write my own Apple Homekit HAP server.

Looking on the official documentation for discovery over IP, using bonjour, there is a TXT record called sh (Setup hash).
I'm guessing this is the code that i need to input into the home app so that it starts pairing. However, i cannot find any more details about this in the documentation. It says "See (”?? ??” (page ??))".

Where could i find more details about this, or is there some more detailed documentation that i could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the setup hash is new in specification revision 2 and does not appear in specification revision 1. In my homekit project (https://github.com/jlusiardi/homekit_python) I did not update this after specification revision 2 came out.

HTH